# How to update a field inside a list in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this collection in Firebase
[image]

I have tried to modify the value within the map notes of a specific subject, I could not do it and I have tried in several ways without success
I would really appreciate a little help.

I get the data in that way, but I can not update that data.

```
this.firestore.collection('school').doc('254')
            .get().toPromise().then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const student = doc.data().class.find(value => {
                    return value.name === 'john';
                });
                console.log('student', student);
                /*
                Here edit student.notes.math = newValue
                 */
            }
        });
```

PD: I'm currently work with Angular 7.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I can get the data I want to update, but I can not update that data.

Comment: Thanks for adding that code, that helps a lot in understanding what you've done. If Doug's answer helps, be sure to indicate so there. If Doug's answer doesn't help yet, please explain/show how what you're doing is different from what he's shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that your code attempts to update the document that you found.  Changing the data in memory doesn't change the contents of the document.  You will have to write additional code to update the document with your changes to the class field.

See:

- [Firestore: How to update specific field of document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184131/firestore-how-to-update-specific-field-of-document)
- The [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md)

```
this.firestore
    .collection('school')
    .doc('254')
    .update("class", NEW_FIELD_CONTENTS)
```

You will need to provide the **entire** contents of the updated class field.  Firestore doesn't have any operations that let you update an array item at a specific index.

Comment: just mention something, update only accepts one parameter, so I passed it like this .update({class: NEW_FIELD_CONTENTS}) .. and thank you

Comment: The underlying JS SDK accepts alternative key/value pairs as different arguments.  I would imagine that Angular's wrapper around that would also, but you're saying that is not the case?