# Firestore: How to update specific field In payload document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I access and update a specific field in angular firebase but My Data In payload I have put the image link that easy for u:

[Enter This Link and see the Image what I am saying that]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZQI.png)

```
 UserVerification(id, _value: number) {


      
     console.log(id,"KKKKK",_value)
    //return this.firestore.collection("DevicesData").doc(id).update({Impact:"100 "}); 
      return this.firestore
     .collection("DevicesData")
     .doc('/' + '00HcetBoNFIOmwEWZ6fo')
    //  .doc(id)
     .update({Impact:"_value"})
     .then(() => {
       console.log('done');
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
     });
    }
```

if I use this code then update the data outside the payload but I want to update the data inside the payload ?

Changes

1.[Add Document in Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZQI.png)

```
Now In this I'll show how can i put the data .first column I write the payload then second column I put string then after last column I put the my data I'll give a data for You soo please put this data in your payload no
{"Topic":"IMPACT","SID":"1","GPSlat":"634312957","GPSlong":"104014716","GPSalt":"49710","GPSspd":"63","GPShead":"29499222","GPSepoch":"1638504105","Impact":"20200"}
```

2.[Second Image you check please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsG9Y.png)

```
Now In second image I'll show what is the data sequence my data is in one line first and your data is after payload :
Topic:"Impact"
impact:"2000"
etc.
after your sequence of data is in one line (in this second image I clearly what the data sequence soo please check the image clearly) after that you try to put the update query to update the data then I'll show my error in third image
```

3.[This is my error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFIS5.png)

```
Now you understand what I am saying that ? Or Not
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: How to update specific field of document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53184131/firestore-how-to-update-specific-field-of-document)

Comment: @MattU NO  In this Answer  particular data is out my payload but my data is inside the payload please you click on the link which I put in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your code yes will update the data outside payload, because you didn't specify that. The right way to update a field inside an object in a document (called nested objects):

```
return this.firestore
           .collection("DevicesData")
           .doc('00HcetBoNFIOmwEWZ6fo')
           .update({'payload.Impact':_value});
```

You can find the whole documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

**But this won't work for you**, because your payload type is not a map (Object) and that is obvious from the double quote, which mean its a string(make sure when you set it in the right way).
However, if you still want it this way, then you have to update the whole payload string, including other values(also you could do this if the payload is an object, like before):

```
return this.firestore
           .collection("DevicesData")
           .doc('00HcetBoNFIOmwEWZ6fo')
           .update({payload:{Topic:'IMPACT', MAC:'...', ..., Impact:_value});
```

**UPDATE**
I did try the structure and the code as follow, which is the right thing to do:
This is the data before:
[image: The data before]

Then I run this code:

```
await firebaseFirestore
        .collection('workflow')
        .doc('jLcWTZBa5Tfjdex5fiYk')
        .update({ 'payload.Impact': 2000 })
        .then(_ => console.info('Success'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

I get Success, and the data become like this:
[image: The data after]

Other than this I really don't know what is your problem.

Comment: when i try first  code then show only one data in firebase thats payload Impact:5555

Comment: but when i try second code then show the error " Convert this code in JSON.parse "after showing this

Comment: When you tired the first code, does the payload type became map? if yes, then as I told you your payload is string not map, then it will overwrite it. From firsbase console(not code) try to add another field to payload then use the first code again, which should update 'Impact' only.

Comment: i try to use many time in different way but when i update this following data this data is replace all payload data and put new payload data i am using this  .update({payload:"{'Impact':'_value'}"}) soo please now what the mistake

Comment: try to help me i try soo many times soo now can u send me the perfect code please

Comment: If you use this ` .update({payload:"{'Impact':'_value'}"})` then you're using the wrong code(Please read the link I send you, it will help you to understand the code and don't forget to chose Nodejs), Don't use double quote around the value (->"{'Impact':'_value'}"<- those are not right), also this way yes will remove other fields, to update one field you need to use the dot notation, which is the first code I gave you, and don't add any other double quote. (If you still facing problems after this I'll update the answer with screenshots )

Comment: when i try to use Dot notation with my code return    this.firestore
     .collection('DevicesData')
     .doc('1Of5BQFNJlOrfLPj89yW')
     .update({payload:`{"Impact":"50000"}`})
     .then(() => {
       console.log('done');
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
     });                                then still showing the same error  it replace the hall data and put only payload:
"{"Impact":"50000"}" this data whats the mistake in my code

Comment: You Understand what I am say ?

Comment: This ` .update({payload:{"Impact":"50000"}}) ` is not the dot notation, this `.update({'payload.Impact':_value});` is the dot notation....... if you use this `.update({payload:{"Impact":"50000"}})` then yes the data of payload will be removed any only has impact

Comment: i am using dot notation after payload: then close after the 5000"} after after this also same error

Comment: .update({ payload:
    ` {"Topic":"IMPACT","MAC":"24:0A:C4:C5:06:64","GPSlat":"634313388","GPSlong":"104007135","GPSalt":"48613","GPSspd":"90","GPShead":"9855246","GPSepoch":"1636362349","Impact":"5000"}`
    
   })

Comment: but when i try to use this the change the hole data but i want only impact data change

Comment: Please see the update of the answer.

Comment: if you don't mind i have some data which i put on your updated answer soo see it the data first after you put the data on your firebase then update the particular field and see what i am saying that oky

Comment: I don't understand could you please be more clear. There is no changes on your question.

Comment: Now You can check my updated question i give three images and also i clearly explain issue and error soo please check this first

Comment: Now You understand i update my question soo please can You check ?

Comment: Of course the payload will only have impact because its string, updating string is removing the old one and put the new one. So I'll say it again you either you make the payload map NOT string and use the dot notation, or update the whole value of that string like this: `update({payload: '{"Topic":"IMPACT","MAC":"24:0A:C4:C5:06:64","GPSlat":"634313388","GPSlong":"104007135","GPSalt":"48613","GPSspd":"90","GPShead":"9855246","GPSepoch":"1636362349","Impact":"5000"}` }'`.

Comment: soo in this case if i want to change the particular one value then again i put the hole payload data this is not the correct way if i want to change only one value then how can i change this is my question i want to change the particular one value in this given update its possbile to change or not

Comment: Please tell me because i try to change the show the same error

Comment: Sorry I didn't notes the comment. To change one value in a String you have to change(to put) the whole fields, and change the value of the field you want. So no you can't change one value in a string.

Comment: its not possible to change the particular filed