# Alternative Syntax or Logic for AngularFireStore Update?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I would like to ask for alternative ways to implement **Update** data in firestore inside a component ts.

Normally I would use a service and subscribe thru it, however, subscribing and using the service became too laggy and our app crashes since our data team injected around 20k+ records due to data migration.

**Normally I do the following the old way:**

```
Via Service:


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CustomerService {
  customerCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection <Customer>;
  customerDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument <Customer>;
  customers: Observable<Customer[]>;

   constructor(
    public angularFireStore: AngularFirestore

  ) 
  {}

    getCustomer() {
    this.customerCollection = this.angularFireStore.collection('customer');
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes => {
      return changes.map( a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Customer;
        data.id=a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })

    }))
    return this.customers;
  }

  addCustomer(customerAdd:Customer) {
    this.customerCollection.add(customerAdd);
  };

  updateCustomer(custcol : Customer) {
    this.customerDoc = this.angularFireStore.doc(`customer/${custcol.id}`);
    this.customerDoc.update(custcol);
  }


}
```

Normally in my Component TS **Old Code**, I just usually put the update on a function like this.

```
 customerList: customerModel[];
 customerDetails : customerModel;
 customerName: any;
 
 addCustomer : Customer ={
    customerNo: '',
    customerAccountNo: '',
    customerName: '',
    customerAddress: '',
    customerContactNo: '',
    customerEmail: ''

  };

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.customerService.getCustomer().subscribe( customerObservable => {
 this.customerList = customerObservable});
}


add() {
 this.addCustomer.customerName = this.customerName //(input comes from ngModel btw)
 this.customerCollection.add(this.addCustomer);
}

update(){
 this.customerDetails.customerName = this.customerName //(input comes from ngModel btw)
 this.customerService.UpdateCustomer(this.customerDetails)
}
```

This works properly and smoothly when we only have 6000+ records, but as stated above after injecting additional records loading and even updating become laggy.

Searching thru solutions, we stop using the service, and put everything inside the component instead , I manage to implement the **Query** (but just ValueChanges, I believe in order to update I should use SnapshotChanges) and **Adding**, however there's very minimal or no documentation at all for the **Update** even on the official AngularFireStore Documentation, that's why I'm struggling for the correct syntax/logic for this one.

Here's my updated Component TS Code

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs'; 
import { Customer } from '../../models/customer.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-client',
  templateUrl: './add-client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-client.component.scss']
})
export class AddClientComponent implements OnInit {

 private customerCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Customer>
 private customerDocs: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>
 customers: Observable<Customer[]>
  
 constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore
  ) { 
    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection<Customer>('customer')
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
  }
 customerList: Customer[];
 customerDetails: Customer;

 addCustomer : Customer ={
    customerNo: '',
    customerAccountNo: '',
    customerName: '',
    customerAddress: '',
    customerContactNo: '',
    customerEmail: ''
 
  };

queryCustomer() {
    
    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('customer',
    ref => ref
    .orderBy('customerName')
    .startAt(this.query)
    .endAt(this.query + "\uf8ff"));
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.valueChanges();
    this.customers.subscribe(
     (data) => (this.customerList = (data)));
  }

add() {
  this.addCustomer.customerName = this.customerName;
  this.customerCollection.add(this.addCustomer);
}

queryCustomer() {
    
    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('customer',
    ref => ref
    .orderBy('customerName')
    .startAt(this.query)
    .endAt(this.query + "\uf8ff"));
    this.customers = this.customerCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes =>{
        return changes.map(a =>{
        const data=a.payload.doc.data() as depositModel;
        data.id=a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
       });
      }
    ));
    this.customers.subscribe(
     (data) => (this.customerList = (data)));
  }


}
```

I did the following attempts, but somehow they don't work

```
update() {
 
  this.customerDocs = this.angularFirestore.doc(`jobOrders/${customerDetails.id}`);
  this.customerDocs.Update(customerDetails);

}
```

I'm really new to this kind of implementation and hopefully, someone could help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [example1](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-a-crud-firebase-documents-in-angular/) and [example2](https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/angular-firebase-crud/), update can be done as :

> Example1  :
>
> ```
> onRename() {
>         if (!this.editForm.value.replaceValue) {
>             this.message = "Cannot Be Empty!";
>         } else {
>             this.firestore.collection('testCollection').doc(this.id).update({ field: this.editForm.value.replaceValue });
>             this.edit = false;
>             this.message2 = '';
>             this.single = null;
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> Example2 :
>
> ```
> updateCoffeeOrder(data) {
>    return
>        this.firestore
>        .collection("coffeeOrders")
>        .doc(data.payload.doc.id)
>        .set({ completed: true }, { merge: true });
> }
> ```

You can refer to the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185375/15774176) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onVp-8BYUSM) on CRUD operations.